# "C" For nest g4cv thermostat

Tags: nest

Weil McLain pcg-4 series 5...old thermostat was a Honeywell digital with batteries..I have 4 wires but only 2 were used red - R & green - W. It's a 2 zone hydronic system. There is a multi tap transformer S84-19 and it shows a c terminal so I tapped off that terminal and when I did setup with the nest app & it detected R & W but not the c wire.  This furnace is heat only and no circuit board. [image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the actual wiring at the boiler please?

Comment: Is there 24VAC between the R and C wires at the stat?

Comment: I found the C terminal on the burner Transformer that the R wire is connected.  All good and working fine.  Thanks

Comment: What I need is the plug in relay on the schematic spst... Having a hard time finding it.  The relay in my system only has 4 pins.  I don't know how to attach pic to comment.